# Can't resolve layout in BottomNavigation Activity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-gridview

So I have my main Bottom Navigation Activity, and there is three section one of which is dashboard. And I want to make a grid of categories in there. I've been trying to follow some guides on youtube about creation of GridView, but it seems to not work in this Bottom Navigation Activity. The main issue is that in my custom adapter in method getView it can't resolve R.layout.category_item but the file exists.
I would be grateful for some workaround or explanation of why it happens.

DashboardFragment class:

```
    public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

    private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;
    String[] category_names = {"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"};
    int[] data ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    GridView gridView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);
        dashboardViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            }
        });

        gridView = root.findViewById(R.id.category_grid);
        CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
        gridView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        return root;
    }


    private class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return category_names.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.category_item,null);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

category_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.dashboard.DashboardFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know if it's the solution of your problem but you don't use any context when you inflate your view

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // inflate the layout for each list row
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).
                inflate(R.layout.layout_list_view_row_items, parent, false);
        }
       ...
}
```